# Meaning of 高2くらいまで

Tags: meaning

I stumbled on 高2くらいまで and i don't know what means this all together...

Answer (score 6):

Without more context, I'd say 高２ is probably shorthand for 高校２年生.  So whatever it's talking about means "until you're/they're about a 2nd year high school student".